# AWS gateway - 500 error as result of misalignment between payloads (‘method executions’) and desired resource model result

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

We are building a final resource tree for our AWS Gateway API comprised of 4 different JSON models, each a subset of the previous one. The goal here is to bring them all into one JSON payload and execute them together successfully.

The problem is knowing what the final JSON is going to look like – we’re close, but not entirely sure. When we go and execute via the “Method Execution” we get a 500 (for failed transformation). So, again, the goal is understanding how the final JSON transformation is supposed to look like.

The first object:

```
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "identifier" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "unique Identifier"
    },
    "templateData" : {
      "$ref":"~path~/models/beneObjectTemplateData"
    }
}
}
```

The second object is a subset of “beneObjectTemplateData”:

```
  "properties" : {
    "beneData" : {
      "$ref":"~path~/models/beneData"
    }
  },
  "description" : "Beneficiary specific data"
}
```

The third object is a subset of “beneData”:

```
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "beneSpecific" : {
      "$ref":"~path~/models/beneSpecific"
    }
  },
  "description" : "Beneficiary data"
}
```

And then the last object is a subset of “beneSpecific”:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "classification" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Type of beneficiary",
      "pattern" : "^(Business|Individual)$"
    },
    "accountNumber" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Required for Wires"
    },
    "localAccountNumber" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Required for iACH"
    }
  }
}
```

This is what we wrote out for the final transformation, but it isn’t working:

```
    "properties": {
        "identifier": "timetrail",
        "templateData": {
            "beneData": {
                "beneSpecific": {
                    "name": "john",
                    "classification": "Individual",
                    "accountnumber": "3243244",
                    "localAccountNumber": ""
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

So, we are wondering what is going wrong here.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "wrote out for the final transformation", but the first thing I notice, if you're trying to create an object that matches your schema, it should not be wrapped in a 'properties' object

Comment: Thank you! We'll be trying to get rid of the 'properties' object - good call on that.

Comment: Removed the properties but still get a 400 error.
Not sure if its the resource model or the JSON but the values that i am passing in the JSON aren't being registered

Comment: You were getting a 500 error and are now getting a 400 error? Sounds like progress. 400 should be indicating a problem with the request, but there isn't enough information here for me to help debug that